# ios UIImagePickerController delay switching to front camera in the first time

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have implemented to launch UIImagePickerController to capture picture. At the first time, rear camera appear fast, then I switch to front camera, it responses very slowly. It seems to take me nearly 15 seconds. I don't know why initing front camera so slow.

Here my code

```
UIImagePickerController * _picker = nil;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    _picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];

    _picker.delegate = self;

    _picker.allowsEditing = NO;

    _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentModalViewController:_picker animated:YES];

}
```

UPDATE: My device is iPad 2 (iOS 7.0), I also test Facebook app on my device, it responses immediately when I switch to front camera. When I test my app on Ipad mini (iOS 6.1.3), it works very well, this problem doesn't happen. Can someone figure me out, it's little missing when initialize UIImagePickerController, I suppose.

UPDATE 2: I wrote an another very simple project. It launches an UIImagePickerController immediately on viewDidLoad of the rootViewController and it works well, UIImagePickerController responses instantly when I switch to front camera. Does anyone have idea for it?

Comment: It seems to take 15 seconds, or it actually takes 15 seconds?

Comment: it fluctuates between 10 to 20 seconds

Comment: i am also facing same problem , can you share the answer

Comment: @shaik riyaz, I'm sorry but I can't find solution. Now I have to temporarily accept it to implement other functions. I'll back to it when other seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do this on new thread would cancel the delay on open url. I bet it is the same delay.
Note: Not yet tested on camera.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(openbrowser_in_background:) toTarget:self withObject:Object];


- (void)openbrowser_in_background:(NSString *)url
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
```

And you might like to change the openURL to

```
[self presentModalViewController:_picker animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank @Horst, I tried your suggestion but problem still appears. I suppose that it not causes by launching picker, because it responses immediately when I present imagepicker. I freeze when I click the switch button to turn into front camera.